# Find the corresponding item in the List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List item in order to display clearly I could visualize the small list follows, that could be hundreds rows.

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate
--------    --------      --------  
12321       Math         08-25-2017  
32342       Physics      08-25-2017  
34345       Chemistry    08-25-2017 
25325       Math         01-25-2018     
44345       Chemistry    01-25-2018
```

I have `ClassName` and `Date` to pass to retrieve the corresponding object. I am having difficulty how to implement `Date` parameter into the LINQ

```
public Course GetClassesByNameAndDate(string className, DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
    Course course  = allCourses.Where( x=> x.ClassName == className & x.StartDate <= date );

}
```

For example, the logic that I implement returns me two classes. However, I only need to have the item which startdate is closer to the given date.

If I pass `today date` and also course name as `Math`, then it should return me `25325 courseID` object from the list.

Even though there are two math courses, but the one which has started `01-25-2018` is the latest course to the given date.

In other example, if I give a date `01-01-2018`, then it should return 12321  that object. Because `01-01-2018` is earlier than the `25325` startdate which is 01-25-2018.

Comment: OrderBy.FirstOrDefault

Comment: Could you use `.Max(x=>x.ClassName == className && x.StartDate <=date);`?

Comment: @DanielShillcock: Nope, `Max` takes a selector, so you can specify what max-value you want to select. You don't pass the filter-predicate, so which item should be returned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, any idea for the following related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684561/find-items-from-the-list-based-on-given-date

Comment: @hotspring: nope, because it's not clear at all whats wrong with the code that you have posted there.

Comment: I am now asking to return a list of items, rather than a single item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`OrderByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx), it's stable sorting so then you can select the first one using [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) or just [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx)

`allCourses.Where( x=> x.ClassName == className && x.StartDate <= date ).OrderByDescending(x=> x.StartDate ).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Any idea for the following related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684561/find-the-list-of-items-from-list-based-on-given-date

Answer (score 0):

You can order the query by the date and take the first like so:

```
Course course  = allCourses.Where( x=> x.ClassName == className & x.StartDate <= date).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).First();;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to return the class with `StartDate` closest to your `date` argument.

If so, you could order by the difference between the dates and then select the first in the order.

```
public Course GetClassesByNameAndDate(string className, DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
    Course course  = allCourses
       .OrderBy( x => (x.StartDate - date).Duration() ) // use duration to turn negative TimeSpans into positive
       .First( x=> x.ClassName == className & x.StartDate <= date );
}
```