# Find items from the list based on given date

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List item in order to display clearly. I could visualize the small list follows, that could be hundreds rows.

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate
--------    --------      --------  
12321       Math         08-25-2017 
14321       Math         08-25-2017   
32342       Physics      08-25-2017  
34345       Chemistry    08-25-2017 
25325       Math         01-25-2018
45329       Math         01-25-2018     
33325       Math         01-25-2018          
44345       Chemistry    01-25-2018
```

I have `ClassName` and `Date` to pass to retrieve the corresponding objects. I am having difficulty how to implement `Date` parameter into the LINQ. The following implementation sorts and returns only one item.

```
public List<Course> GetClassesByNameAndDate(string className, DateTime date, List<Courses> allCourses)
{
    List<Course> courses  = allCourses.Where( x=> x.ClassName == className && x.StartDate <= date ).OrderByDescending(x=> x.StartDate ).ToList();

}
```

If I pass `today date` and also course name as `Math`, then it should return me `25325,45329,33325 courseIDs` objects from the list.

In other example, if I give a date `01-01-2018`, then it should return `12321, 14321` objects. Because `01-01-2018` is earlier than the `25325,45329,33325` startdate which is `01-25-2018`.

Comment: Your code should not even compile. Why? The compiler should yell at you and saying impossible to store one instance (`FirstOrDefault()` to a list `List<Course>` varaible.

Comment: But if I do not put FirstOrDefault(), then it would return the older date as well. I only want to return the items which date is smaller and closer than the given date,

Comment: So replace it with `ToList()`

Comment: Use take to limit the number of results to what you need. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You have edited your question. What is the actual issue (now)? In what way is it different to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683853/find-the-corresponding-item-in-the-list)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Now, it should return a list of item rather than a single object.

Comment: @hotspring: yes, is it correct? _"I only want to return the items where start date is smaller to the given date"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter given date should be bigger than `startdate` and if that returns multiple objects with multiple different dates, then I need to return closest bigger date items. Question has not been changed, except multiple items.

Comment: @hotspring: in what way is this different to your last question? Why does the accepted answer there doesnt work?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Now it should return a list of item, if you check list item closely, you will see multiple Math courses starts at the same date.

Comment: @hotspring: what is the desired result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are total 5 Math courses in the list. If I pass `today date` (06-04-2018) and also course name as `Math` to the `GetClassesByNameAndDate` method, then it should return me `25325,45329,33325` courseIDs objects from the list. It should not include `12321, 14321` items because there are other Math courses (`25325,45329,33325`) start dates are bigger than `12321, 14321`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess finally i have understood the requirement. You don't want only one item. You also don't want the list with all items where the `startDate` is `<= date`. But you want the whole group of items with the closest start-date(if all of them have **the same `startDate`**). You can `GroupBy` the date:

```
List<Course> courses  = allCourses
    .Where( x=> x.ClassName == className && x.StartDate <= date )
    .OrderByDescending(x=> x.StartDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.ToList() ?? new List<Course>();
```